# URL/HTML Escaping/Encoding, Is escaping `&` from URL's actually required?

Tags: html, url

I have always been very confused with URL/HTML Escaping. More recently I looked deeper into it. Then looking at the PHP Docs for [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
```

I then realized that theres `&` in most query strings that seems like should be escaped. But it seems to work without escaping. I wonder why, and if its actually required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping `&` into `&amp;` is required in HTML, but it works in most browsers anyway. If it wouldn't, 90% of the Internet would break. :) It still is good style to escape ampersands, and it is required for the document to pass validation.

See this W3C document for some good background *why* (the text focuses on a specific behaviour of PHP, but that doesn't really matter): [Ampersands, PHP Sessions and Valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/QA/2005/04/php-session). Money quote (emphasis mine):

> In order to display reserved characters HTML and XHTML provide a mechanism called character references. The syntax of these is:
>
> - an ampersand
> - a "code" for the referenced character
> - a semicolon
> - For example, the "less than" character is represented as `&lt;`.
>
> Giving the ampersand special meaning makes it, like <, a reserved character, **so it also needs to be represented by an entity for it to be used in a document** - `&amp`;

Comment: So it seems like `http://test?param1=1&amp;param2=2` will be converted to `http://test?param1=1&param2=2` by the browser?

Comment: `&amp;` is HTML for "An ampersand". So the browser will convert it, just as it converts `<p>` to "A paragraph".

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

Inside of an HTML document, the ampersand character (`&`) is not allowed, except when specifying an entitiy (such as `&amp;`).

Therefore, code such as `<a href='mycgi?foo=1&bar=2'>` is invalid HTML. It should throw an error if you run it through a validator.

Most (all?) browsers will cope with it without an error though. There's no ambiguity here, so it will work.

However, it is still a good idea to convert them into entities anyway, because there is always the possibility of an ambiguity creeping in - for example, if you have a parameter in your URL named `amp` instead of `bar`, how would the browser deal with that? It's not quite as clear cut. So you should convert them all to entities to avoid any future issues, even if you don't have any now.

Comment: How the browser deals with `&amp=` in a URL in an HTML document is pretty clear cut. The semi-colon is optional (in HTML) since it is followed by an `=`. So it doesn't need to perform error recovery (since it isn't an error according to the spec) and treats it as data meaning "an ampersand followed by an equals"